# Equation of a rectangle in $R^{n}$

Tags: calculus, geometry, polytopes, rectangles

I have 4 points in $R^{8}$, which make a rectangle with length $2$ and width $sqrt(2)$. The vertices are:

$(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),(1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1),(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)$

what is the equation of this rectangle in $R^{8}&?

In general I am wondering if we are given 4 points in $R^{n}$ what is the equation of that rectangle?! But if you just could solve my question in $R^{8}$ that’s fine! I will apperatiate !

Comment: what do you mean by "equation of a rectangle"?

Comment: @gimusi   For example in $R^{2}$ it is $a<x<b , c<y<d$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In your example you said $a<x<b$, $c<y<d$, but how would you find the equation of a slanted rectangle?

Comment: In $R^{2}$ with finding the equation of the lines

Comment: Can you determine which lines are parallel to which in $R8$?

Comment: Yes, the first and third points and the second and forth

Answer (score 0):

Wrong, those 4 points do span a 3D subspace.
In fact those are 4 vertices from a cube of edge length $\sqrt{2}$.

$\overline{AC} = \overline{CD} = \overline{DB} = \sqrt{2}$ (: edges)
$\overline{AD} = \overline{CB} = \sqrt{4}$ (: square diagonals)
$\overline{AB} = \sqrt{6}$ (: body diagonal)

--- rk